# Type '{ ref: RefObject<IHandles>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IHandles': open, close

Tags: react-native, expo

I use this libary:

```
https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize
```

Why I get this error message ?

```
Type '{ ref: RefObject<IHandles>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IHandles': open, close
```

This error comes at <ModalGender <- ... />

App.tsx

```
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

const modalizeRef = useRef<Modalize>();
<ModalGender ref={modalizeRef} />
```

ModalGender.tsx

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Button } from '../../Button';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

interface IModalGenderProps {};

export const ModalGender = forwardRef<IModalGenderProps, Modalize>((_, ref) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
 
  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={ref}
      adjustToContentHeight
    >
      <View style={s.container}>
        <View style={s.buttonContainer}>
          <Button style={s.btn}>
            <FontAwesome name="male" size={24} color="#444" />
            <Text>{t('male')}</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button style={s.btn}>
            <FontAwesome name="male" size={24} color="#444" />
            <Text>{t('male')}</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modalize>
  )
});
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ts error

Comment: Have you seen this setup guide for Android/Expo: https://jeremybarbet.github.io/react-native-modalize/#/INSTALLATION

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I use expo

Comment: And you have react-native-gesture-handler installed and linked?